# SPARQL query works on the Fuseki interface but in Jena

Tags: java, sparql, jena, fuseki

THis is my query

```sql
    PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix no: <http://www.newontology.org/no#>
prefix rs: <http://semanticrecommender.com/rs#>
prefix mo: <http://music.org/musicontology/mo#>
prefix : <http://www.MusicSemanticOntology.com/mso#>

select ?item (SUM(?similarity * ?importance * ?levelImportance * ?ratingValue) as ?summedSimilarity) 
(group_concat(distinct ?x) as ?commingFromLikingThisInstance)
(group_concat(?becauseOf ; separator = " ,and ") as ?reason)
where
{
  values ?user { :ania }
  #the variable ?x is bound to the items the user :ania has liked.
  ?user rs:hasRated ?ratings.
  ?ratings a rs:Likes.
  ?ratings rs:about ?x.
  ?ratings rs:ratesBy ?ratingValue.
 ?ratings rs:createdOn ?ratingDate.

  #level 0 class similarities
  {
    #extract all the items that are from the same class (type) as the liked items.
    #I assumed the being from the same class accounts for 50% of the similarities.
    #This value can be changed according to the test or the application domain.
    values ?classImportance {0.5} #class level
    ?x  a ?class .
    ?item a ?class .
    ?class rs:hasSimilarityValue ?similarity .
    bind (?classImportance as ?importance)
    bind( 4/7 as ?levelImportance)
    bind (concat("it shares the same class, which is ", str(?class), " with ", str(?x)) as ?becauseOf)
  }


}
group by ?item
order by desc(?summedSimilarity)
```

it works if i put it in fuseki sparql interface, but if i put it in a file and call that file from jena, i get the follwong exception:

```
EVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.semanticrecommender.web.Main] in context with path [/SemanticRecommender] threw exception
HttpException: 400
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.http.HttpQuery.rewrap(HttpQuery.java:411)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.http.HttpQuery.execPost(HttpQuery.java:399)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.http.HttpQuery.exec(HttpQuery.java:291)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP.execResultSetInner(QueryEngineHTTP.java:359)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP.execSelect(QueryEngineHTTP.java:351)
```

eventhough I print the query that jena loads from the file and copied it to fuseki and it works perfectly on fuseki

This is how I load the query (but I am sure this is not related to the actual problem)

```
InputStream testIn = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/recommend.rq");
        String queryTemplate = IOUtils.toString(testIn);
System.out.println(queryTemplate);
        QueryExecution x = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(
                "http://localhost:3030/rs/query", queryTemplate);
        ResultSet results = x.execSelect();
        ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results);
```

#### Update

This code work

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix no: <http://www.newontology.org/no#>
prefix rs: <http://semanticrecommender.com/rs#>
prefix mo: <http://music.org/musicontology/mo#>
prefix : <http://www.MusicSemanticOntology.com/mso#>

select *
where
{
  values ?user { :ania }
  #the variable ?x is bound to the items the user :ania has liked.
  ?user rs:hasRated ?ratings.
  ?ratings a rs:Likes.
  ?ratings rs:about ?x.
  ?ratings rs:ratesBy ?ratingValue.
 ?ratings rs:createdOn ?ratingDate.

  #level 0 class similarities
  {
    #extract all the items that are from the same class (type) as the liked items.
    #I assumed the being from the same class accounts for 50% of the similarities.
    #This value can be changed according to the test or the application domain.
    values ?classImportance {0.5} #class level
    ?x  a ?class .
    ?item a ?class .
    ?class rs:hasSimilarityValue ?similarity .
    bind (?classImportance as ?importance)
    bind( 4/7 as ?levelImportance)
    bind (concat("it shares the same class, which is ", str(?class), " with ", str(?x)) as ?becauseOf)
  }


}
```

**These two queries are identical except the group by, the one with group by works just on Fuseki interface, not eclipse java, but the other works with both**

#### Update3

The problem happens in these two lines

```
(group_concat(distinct ?x) as ?commingFromLikingThisInstance)
(group_concat(?becauseOf ; separator = " ,and ") as ?reason)
```

when I remove them, everything works fine, but when I put them I got that error

#### Update 4

The log is:

```
2016-03-28 11:17:50 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:63 - << "Error 400: Parse error: [\n]"
2016-03-28 11:17:50 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:63 - << "PREFIX  :     <http://www.MusicSemanticOntology.com/mso#>[\n]"
2016-03-28 11:17:50 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:63 - << "PREFIX  rs:   <http://semanticrecommender.com/rs#>[\n]"
2016-03-28 11:17:50 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:63 - << "PREFIX  rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>[\n]"
2016-03-28 11:17:50 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:63 - << "PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>[\n]"
2016-03-28 11:17:50 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:63 - << "[\n]"
2016-03-28 11:17:50 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:63 - << "SELECT  ?item (SUM(( ( ( ?similarity * ?importance ) * ?levelImportance ) * ?ratingValue )) AS ?summedSimilarity) (GROUP_CONCAT DISTINCT (?x) AS ?commingFromLikingThisInstance) (GROUP_CONCAT (?becauseOf ; separator=' ,and ') AS ?reason)[\n]"
2016-03-28 11:17:50 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:63 - << "WHERE[\n]"
2016-03-28 11:17:50 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:63 - << "  { VALUES ?user { :ania }[\n]"
2016-03-28 11:17:50 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:63 - << "    ?user     rs:hasRated  ?ratings .[\n]"
2016-03-28 11:17:50 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:63 - << "    ?ratings  rdf:type     rs:Likes ;[\n]"
2016-03-28 11:17:50 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:63 - << "              rs:about     ?x ;[\n]"
2016-03-28 11:17:50 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:63 - << "              rs:ratesBy   ?ratingValue[\n]"
2016-03-28 11:17:50 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:63 - << "    { VALUES ?classImportance { 0.5 }[\n]"
2016-03-28 11:17:50 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:63 - << "      BIND(?classImportance AS ?importance)[\n]"
2016-03-28 11:17:50 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:63 - << "      BIND(( 4 / 7 ) AS ?levelImportance)[\n]"
2016-03-28 11:17:50 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:63 - << "      ?x      rdf:type              ?class .[\n]"
2016-03-28 11:17:50 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:63 - << "      ?item   rdf:type              ?class .[\n]"
2016-03-28 11:17:50 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:63 - << "      ?class  rs:hasSimilarityValue  ?similarity[\n]"
2016-03-28 11:17:50 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:63 - << "      BIND(concat("it shares the same class, which is ", str(?class), " with ", str(?x)) AS ?becauseOf)[\n]"
2016-03-28 11:17:50 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:63 - << "    }[\n]"
2016-03-28 11:17:50 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:63 - << "  }[\n]"
2016-03-28 11:17:50 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:63 - << "GROUP BY ?item[\n]"
2016-03-28 11:17:50 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:63 - << "ORDER BY DESC(?summedSimilarity)[\n]"
2016-03-28 11:17:50 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:63 - << "[\n]"
2016-03-28 11:17:50 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:63 - << "[\r]Encountered " "distinct" "DISTINCT "" at line 6, column 129.[\n]"
2016-03-28 11:17:50 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:63 - << "Was expecting:[\n]"
2016-03-28 11:17:50 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:63 - << "    "(" ...[\n]"
2016-03-28 11:17:50 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:63 - << "    [\n]"
2016-03-28 11:17:50 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:63 - << "[\n]"
2016-03-28 11:17:50 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:63 - << "[\n]"
2016-03-28 11:17:50 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:63 - << "Fuseki - version 2.3.1 (Build date: 2015-12-08T09:24:07+0000)[\n]"
2016-03-28 11:17:50 DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager:274 - Connection [id: 0][route: {}->http://localhost:3030] can be kept alive indefinitely
2016-03-28 11:17:50 DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager:281 - Connection released: [id: 0][route: {}->http://localhost:3030][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 5; total allocated: 1 of 10]
```

#### Update 5

Now I found the real problem, it is the word `DISTINCT`, when I remove it, everything works fine, when I put it back, it just works from the fuseki interface and not from jena java :( help guys please

Comment: Is that really the full stack trace?  There's not more "caused by..." below that?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor the other stack are from apache tomcat that calls the function.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I also found this on the fuseki-server termianl (cmd) `Encountered " "distinct" "DISTINCT "" at line 8, column 129.
Was expecting:
    "(" ...
     (37 ms)
` again the query works perfectly on fuseki interface (localhost:3030)

Comment: based on what you're seeing with distinct,  you can probably find a much smaller query that has the same problem (works in Web interface but not programmatically ). That's part of the process of isolating the problem.  If you can do that, it will be what's easier for everyone who does not have access to your data and setup to see what the problem is. Or you might figure out what the problem is just by doing that.

Comment: Can you make the query shorter and still get the problem?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor well I tried another query (small one) and it works on both of they. Let me try to make it easier (or smaller) and I will update you.

Comment: yes, try to isolate the change that goes from working to not working.  That change is very likely where the problem is. This is the usual process of debugging, and yes, it can be a bit tedious sometimes.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I changed it to the least possible form and I still have the problem :(

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor happy Easter as well

Comment: if you have a small query where the problem still occurs, why not add it to the question?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I did, I updated my question and put the small query, and I will update now to add the one that works. I mean you would need to read the question again, because I updated the same already existed code

Comment: I'm looking at your question now.  There's one big query that doesn't work, and one big query that works.  I find it hard to believe that those are the smallest queries that demonstrate the problem. You can't reproduce the problem with a smaller query?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor actually they are the same query (exactly the same) without just the grouping in the select. could you give it another look please?

Comment: It would have been good to mention in the question, that the queries are the same except for the group by. Not everyone reads the comments, especially when there are lots of them. Comments can be deleted at any time.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Okay I added that to the question.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I found the reason of the problem, kindly could you check my update 3? but I don't know the solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might want to have Jena avoid the local parsing if you can, in this case, and send the query directly to the remote endpoint.  That approach is described in the [jena throws QueryParsingException on correct but non-standard SPARQL](https://web.archive.org/web/20150109202315/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/19935/jena-throws-queryparsingexception-on-correct-but-non-standard-sparql) question on answers.semanticweb.com.  The idea would be to create a **QueryEngineHTTP** with the query string.

As to **why** you're getting this error, I think it might be a bug on Jena's end.  I have a little bit of evidence, and a little bit of hypothesis. Investigating a bit more, and playing with [sparql.org's query validator](http://sparql.org/validate/query) (which is backed by Jena), there's something weird going on.  If you enter the query

```
select (group_concat(distinct ?x) as ?y) (sum(distinct ?x) as ?z) {}
```

into the parser, the formatted, parsed query appears as:

```
SELECT  (GROUP_CONCAT DISTINCT (?x) AS ?y) (SUM(DISTINCT ?x) AS ?z) WHERE {}
```

which is *not* legal. (Note the off placement of distinct with the
GROUP_CONCAT. Also note that it happens with **group_concat**, but not with **sum**.)

When a query is sent to a remote endpoint using Jena, if Jena first
parses the input query, and then sends the reformatted query off to the
remote endpoint, that would explain debug log messages and the parse error, but 
I'm not sure whether that's how things are implemented or not.

Comment: but I didn't write `(GROUP_CONCAT DISTINCT (?x) AS ?commingFromLikingThisInstance)` from the first place, I already wrote `(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?x) AS ?commingFromLikingThisInstance)` could you check please

Comment: Hmm,  the debug log you posted has the thing I wrote, but you're right in that I don't see it in the code you posted.  Are you reading the query in from a file somewhere?  Or coping and pasting it?  We may be getting closer to a solution...

Comment: @Ania in your question,  you wrote " when I remove it, everything works fine, when I put it back, it just works from the fuseki interface and not from jena" are you sure that type passing it back in the same place? It would only be take one character being off too paste it back in the way is shown in the debug log.

Comment: I am reading from a file, the query is stored in a file in my resources, when i remove the word `DISTINCT` it works perfectly, (even though the query is tooooo long), but when I put the word `DISTINCT` it stoped working, i don't know why the log is like this bty, do you want to show you the file ?

Comment: I didn't understand your second comment please, could you repeat using simple english?

Comment: i already copied paste the code that is not working in the `update 3` from the question, you can see that i wrote it correct. believe me i have checked for syntax error for 2 days. it is an old problem as you know

Comment: @ania the debug log is reporting that it is seeing `GROUP_CONCAT distinct (...` not `GROUP_CONCAT  (distinct...`. Unless that's just how the debug log prints things,  it would be useful to find out why the debug log is printing something *different* from your query in your file.

Comment: I was going to say the **same** thing, the log removes the `(` and that is the problem. this is my query `(group_concat( distinct  ?x) ` i sware, but in the log the print it without the `(` i tried that now with a very small query, and the result the same, the log not showing the `(`

Comment: I also print the query in eclipse, which was loaded from the file, before executing it, and the query is correct, it has the `(` as well

Comment: Kindly no idea for a solution ?

Comment: @AniaDavid It looks like whatever is producing that debug log is seeing a different query than what you say you're passing to it.  I'd  try to track down why that's happening.  Maybe it's reading a cached version of a file, or you have multiple files, and forgot to update a filename;  there are lots of options.  Of, if there's a bug where the endpoint sees `select (group_concat(distinct ?x) as ?y) ...` and thinks it's `select (group_concat distinct (?x) as ?y) ...`, then you should be able to reproduce that with a very small test case that you can report to the Jena developers.

Comment: @AniaDavid Actually, it looks like it might be some kind of bug.  If you go to [sparql.org's query validator](http://sparql.org/validate/query), which runs Jena and ask it to parse a query like `select (group_concat(distinct ?x) as ?y) (sum(distinct ?x) as ?z) {}`, the parsed results show:  ` SELECT  (GROUP_CONCAT DISTINCT (?x) AS ?y) (SUM(DISTINCT ?x) AS ?z)`, which looks like what you're seeing in your system.  I wonder if your code is parsing the query, then sending the parsed representation, rather than the original string, and the syntax error is getting injected?

Comment: @AniaDavid At any rate, how important is the `distinct` in your results?  Can you just remove it?

Comment: it is not a cash thing at all, i am sure there is a buy, i will make a small prototype and tell jena, even though i already send them, they just look at the log, they didn't see the query ,they replied by saying that my sentax is wrong (the same you said), but they didn't see that my sentax is correct but just the log is wrong

Comment: it is very important, because it is what i tell the user, so if i remove it, it will be something like this: i recommend you these 10 items because based on the following items that you have liked (song 1, song 1, song 1) .... but actually with distinct it will be: based on the following items that you have liked (song1)

Comment: @AniaDavid I actually just sent a message to the user list (and updated my answer with a very similar text).  I created a very small test case, and sparql.org's query validator shows the same disconnect between input and output.  If Jena's code is parsing the query, and then sending the re-formatted query to the remote endpoint, it would be *injecting* the syntax error into your query.  That's a rather nasty bug, if that's what's happening.

Comment: I hope that you're starting to see the value in creating *minimal* examples here.  If the bug is what it looks like, it didn't end up requiring much of a SPARQL query at all to test it.  That's part of the process of debugging.

Comment: I already started to try this minimal thing, in this question, how could I know that it is the distinct? and when you told me that i need to make it smaller, i made a smaller query, and then i found that the error in the two lines of group_concat, then i found the error in distinct, and for all that i made update to the question. i can't know in advance the reason of the problem,

Comment: I meant to say that I am trying also, not just asking without trying, as the rule for Stackoverflow

Comment: @AniaDavid And neither can anyone else.  That's part of the debugging process;  trying to isolate problems, and running things that you think *should* work, and finding the one that *doesn't*.  In this case, the log says you're passing `group_concat distinct (?x)`, which you know you're not, so you'd try a minimal query that *only* does `group_concat(distinct ?x)` and look at what the log says.  When it says `group_concat distinct (?x)`, you know you've isolated something strange, and can ask about that specifically.

Comment: that is right, thanks, I will do that now, with a working code to allow jena to try themselves also

Comment: @AniaDavid There may be a workaround using QueryEnginerHTTP.  I've updated my answer.  It's not a technique I've used before, but I think it may be what you need until this apparent bug is fixed.

Comment: please how did you find my email to jena about the error? is it on a website? I though i was texting them because i was using my email not a web fourm

Comment: @AniaDavid You weren't texting, you were sending an email to a public mailing list.  The archives are available at https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jena-users/.  You didn't *text* them, you *emailed* them.

Comment: It sounds like for some reasons I can't subscribe to that group, anyway I just need to know if they will fix that or not and if yes (maybe they did), how can I make it work again? do I need to download the jena libraries again? Plus, I found another bug :) could you please check my new question?

Comment: please what do I do? there is a bug, jena not replying on this mail list.

Comment: @AniaDavid If you read Andy Seaborne's response to some of the messages, you'll see that he said it's been fixed, and will be available in a future release.  I did post the link to the public archives of the mailing list.

Comment: thanks, I though that the bug will be fixed and I will be able to use the new code, so please how can I know when will the new release appear? (i still have until april 13 to finish, i hope they do before, and im still with the problem of adding pellet to fuseki)

Comment: You could try to use the new release, but why not just use the Query http engine as suggested in some of the comments?  That would work with the current release.

Comment: using the http is a possible and i will do next week if they don't fix the problem, I had already developed a dynamic system in which it takes the parameter from the user and automatically redirect to the correct sparql template and call fuseki using jena and return the results to the user. so using the http would mean make some exceptions in my system, and now i need to spend the time fixing this, extremly un happy, pellet problem.

Comment: Now I looked at the maven repository , it still the same version that I'm using http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jena/apache-jena-libs/3.0.1 i tried, though, to update the library, but stil the same error, sounds like they haven't updated it yet

Comment: @AniaDavid Just because they've made a change in the code, I wouldn't expect it to be automatically released as a new version immediately and third-party repositories to pick it up.  I might release a new product, but it doesn't mean stores suddenly start carrying it.